# Scraping web data

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, request

I'd like to **scrape** the data from a website: https://en.macromicro.me/charts/773/baltic-dry-index
,which comprises 4 data sets.

I've discovered that the website use javascript to send request to https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/773
to get the data,but for some reason i just can't get the data by using Postman or my script. i keep getting the result: {'success': 0, 'data': [], 'msg': 'error #240'}

did I miss anything here?
here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import datetime
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/773'
header = {
'sec-ch-ua':'"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Docref': 'https://www.google.com/',
'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?0',
'Authorization':'Bearer ee1c7b87258a902bde1129df2b64abac',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get(url,headers = header)
response = json.loads(r.text)
response
```

[image: Data SETS]

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `Cookie` in headers.
Refresh the page to get cookies.

Comment: i did add the cookie though it didn't work. do you make it?

Comment: Yes, I tried again. Both values have been verified: `Cookie` and `Authorization`. Copy them from the same request and it works. And it has an expiration time. May be you should try use selenium.